# Watch a Git repository on Google Code? (RSS/Twitter/...)

Tags: google-code

There is [a Git repository](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/source/list) that I want to be notified about. Any notificatioin would be fine: RSS would be the best, but Twitter or similar notifications are acceptable too. Unfortunately, the page is not understood by [Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com):

```
Your feed might be empty or missing publish dates or GUIDs
```

Is there another service that understands [Git history](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) and pushes a notification when a new commit is made?

Actually [this open source project](https://github.com/scotchi/gitfeed) has most of the code that would be needed to create such a service.

Comment: Just to double check, [this feed](http://code.google.com/feeds/p/leveldb/gitchanges/basic) doesn't work for you?

Comment: @JohnC: Whao, it works! Where did you find it? Could not find any documentation about this feature... please post as an answer so that I can accept

Comment: I see now in the HTML source: <link type="application/atom+xml" rel="alternate" href="/feeds/p/leveldb/gitchanges/basic"> Too bad Firefox tells me nothing about it.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?  I tried that page in Opera 12 and SeaMonkey 2.12.1 and both found it.

Comment: Google Code no longer exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer to the question the feed is [here](http://code.google.com/feeds/p/leveldb/gitchanges/basic).

As a bonus note: Firefox [removed the RSS button](http://decafbad.com/blog/2011/01/15/what-happened-to-feed-autodiscovery-in-firefox-4) over a year ago because allegedly only 3% of users used it. You can still check if a page has an RSS by going **Bookmarks** → **Subscribe to this page** or by right clicking on the tool bar, selecting **Customise** and dragging the icon back to its rightful place.